# Find maximum from combination of two tables (for-loop too slow)

Tags: r, plyr, data.table, reshape2

I have a data table "the.data", where the first column indicate a measurement instrument, and the rest different measured data.

```
instrument <- c(1,2,3,4,5,1,2,3,4,5)
hour <- c(1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2)
da <- c(12,14,11,14,10,19,15,16,13,11)
db <- c(21,23,22,29,28,26,24,27,26,22)
the.data <- data.frame(instrument,hour,da,db)
```

I also have defined groups of instruments, where for example group 1 (g1) refers to instruments 1 and 2.

```
g1 <- c(1,2)
g2 <- c(4,3,1)
g3 <- c(1,5,2)
g4 <- c(2,4)
g5 <- c(5,3,1,2,6)
groups <- c("g1","g2","g3","g4","g5")
```

I need to find out at which hour the sum of each group has maximum per data type, and its sum.

g1 hour 1: sum(da)=12+14=26
g1 hour 2: sum(da)=19+15=34

So, for g1 and da the answer is hour 2 and value 34.

I did this with a for-loop within a for-loop, but it takes too long time (I interrupted after a few hours). The issue is that the.data is about 100.000 rows long and that there are about 5.000 groups with 2-50 instruments each.

What can be a good method to do this?

Sincere thanks to all contributors to Stack-overflow.

Update: Now only five groups in examples.

/Chris

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `group` loop will have to stay, or at best be replaced by something like `lapply()`. The `hour` loop, however, can be totally replaced by reformatting to an `instrument x hour` matrix and then just doing vectorized algebra. For example:

```
library(reshape2)

groups = list(g1, g3)

the.data.a = dcast(the.data[,1:3], instrument ~ hour)

> sapply(groups, function(x) data.frame(max = max(colSums(the.data.a[x, -1])),
                                        ind = which.max(colSums(the.data.a[x, -1]))))
    [,1] [,2]
max 34   45  
ind 2    2
```

Comment: It runs with two groups but throws an error for me with five groups.

Comment: @DWin That's cause only instruments 1-5 are in the example data. The other groups reference instruments that aren't present.

Comment: Thanks for quick and very good answer. From reading here, I realized that I had missed some instruments in "the.data" and corrected, but it turned out that my real data had missing measurements too (in Hour, not in Instrument).

Comment: @Chris Great, glad it helped. Good luck with your project!

Answer (score 3):

Here's a slightly modified version of [John Colby's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10288990/271616), with some sample data.

```
set.seed(21)
instrument <- sample(100, 1e5, TRUE)
hour <- sample(24, 1e5, TRUE)
da <- trunc(runif(1e5)*10)
db <- trunc(runif(1e5)*10)
the.data <- data.frame(instrument,hour,da,db)
groups <- replicate(5000, sample(100, sample(50,1)))
names(groups) <- paste("g",1:length(groups),sep="")

library(reshape2)
system.time({    
the.data.a <- dcast(the.data[,1:3], instrument ~ hour, sum)
out <- t(sapply(groups, function(i) {
  byHour <- colSums(the.data.a[i,-1])
  c(max(byHour), which.max(byHour))
}))
colnames(out) <- c("max.hour","max.sum")
})
# Using da as value column: use value.var to override.
#    user  system elapsed 
#    3.80    0.00    3.81
```

Comment: Nice example, Josh! I'm always curious how fast we can get these things.

Answer (score 2):

Here's one approach using `plyr` and `reshape2` from Hadley. First, we'll add some boolean values to `the.data` depending on whether or not the instrument is in that group. Then we'll melt it into long format, subset out the rows we don't need, and then do a group by operation with `ddply` or `data.table`.

```
#add boolean columns
the.data <- transform(the.data, 
                      g1 = instrument %in% g1,
                      g2 = instrument %in% g2,
                      g3 = instrument %in% g3,
                      g4 = instrument %in% g4,
                      g5 = instrument %in% g5
                      )

#load library
library(reshape2)
#melt into long format
the.data.m <- melt(the.data, id.vars = 1:4)
#subset out data that that has FALSE for the groupings
the.data.m <- subset(the.data.m, value == TRUE)

#load plyr and data.table
library(plyr)
library(data.table)

#plyr way
ddply(the.data.m, c("variable", "hour"), summarize, out = sum(da))
#data.table way
dt <- data.table(the.data.m)
dt[, list(out = sum(da)), by = "variable, hour"]
```

Do some benchmarking to see which is faster:

```
library(rbenchmark)   
f1 <- function() ddply(the.data.m, c("variable", "hour"), summarize, out = sum(da))
f2 <- function() dt[, list(out = sum(da)), by = "variable, hour"]

> benchmark(f1(), f2(), replications=1000, order="elapsed", columns = c("test", "elapsed", "relative"))
  test elapsed relative
2 f2()    3.44 1.000000
1 f1()    6.82 1.982558
```

So, data.table is about 2x faster for this example. Your miles may vary.

And just to show that it's giving right values:

```
> dt[, list(out = sum(da)), by = "variable, hour"]
      variable hour out
 [1,]       g1    1  26
 [2,]       g1    2  34
 [3,]       g2    1  25
 [4,]       g2    2  29

...
```

Comment: I don't think your code is handling the choices of max and which.max yet.

Comment: @Dwin - doh, you're right! I misread / glossed over that earlier, will update in a bit. Thanks, -chase

Answer (score 2):

You didn't provide your code (or a programmatic way to generate the groups, which would seem to be needed with a group count of 5000)  but this *may* be a more effective use of R:

```
groups <- list(g1,g2,g3,g4,g5)
gmax <- list()
# The "da" results
for( gitem in seq_along(groups) ) { 
       gmax[[gitem]] <- with( subset(the.data , instrument %in% groups[[gitem]]),  
                               tapply(da , hour, sum) ) }
damat <- matrix(c(sapply(gmax, which.max), 
                  sapply(gmax, max)) , ncol=2)

# The "db" results
for( gitem in seq_along(groups) ) { 
       gmax[[gitem]] <- with( subset(the.data , instrument %in% groups[[gitem]]),  
                               tapply(db , hour, sum) ) }
dbmat <- matrix(c(sapply(gmax, which.max), 
                  sapply(gmax, max)) , ncol=2)

#--------
> damat
     [,1] [,2]
[1,]    2   34
[2,]    2   29
[3,]    2   45
[4,]    1   14
[5,]    2   42
> dbmat
     [,1] [,2]
[1,]    2   50
[2,]    2   53
[3,]    1   72
[4,]    1   29
[5,]    1   73
```